# iOS Push Notification Shows up as UIAlert when App is Running

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, push, uialertview

I have push notifications successfully set up on my app.  When I send a push to a user when they are not running the app they receive it banner-style as they should.

However, when a user has the app open, instead of displaying the push notification as a banner it shows up as a UIAlert.  Receiving pushes only behaves this way when the app is open.

I have the "Alert Style When Unlocked" set up as "Banner" (on both phones), and this behavior persists.

Comment: What code do you have in your app delegate `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method?

Answer (score 3):

When Applicationn is running you will get call in didReceiveRemoteNotification method on AppDelegate Class , so now you can handle notification here :

Now You can create a custom view and add it to your application main window as a banner.

Answer (score 0):

The settings is for App in background, show as Banner or Alert. When App is opened it calls `didReceiveRemoteNotification` directly, and no Banner or Alert show up.